# Where does iOS store property data on the filesystem?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Where does iOS store property data? For example, I would like to find where the identity value of the Threema iOS App gets stored on the device itself:

https://github.com/threema-ch/threema-ios/blob/main/Threema/MyIdentityStore.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyIdentityStore : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic, readwrite) NSString *identity;
@property (strong, nonatomic, readwrite) NSString *serverGroup;
@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) NSData *publicKey;

@property (strong, nonatomic, readwrite) NSString *pushFromName;
@property (strong, nonatomic, readwrite) NSMutableDictionary *profilePicture;

@property (nonatomic, readwrite) BOOL linkEmailPending;
@property (strong, nonatomic, readwrite) NSString *linkedEmail;

@property (nonatomic, readwrite) BOOL linkMobileNoPending;
@property (strong, nonatomic, readwrite) NSString *linkMobileNoVerificationId;
@property (strong, nonatomic, readwrite) NSDate *linkMobileNoStartDate;
@property (strong, nonatomic, readwrite) NSString *linkedMobileNo;
```

I checked the ThreemaData.sqlite and group.ch.threema.plist files but I could not find the data in there.

Comment: instance properties, as you have shown,  are just in-memory values.  Looking at the corresponding .m file, the identity object is stored in the keychain. So it isn't stored on the filesystem anywhere

Comment: At least, not in the app's sandboxes file system. The keychain file is in the system file system